# Outgoing TCP traffic redirection

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, tcp, redirection

I have a program that attempts to communicate with an old server on the 1.1.1.1:5555 (for instance) using TCP. The problem is that I  no longer have access to that IP (my new server works on 2.2.2.2:6666 (example)).

I want to redirect all **outgoing** traffic coming to 1.1.1.1:5555 to 2.2.2.2:6666, so as to save myself the pain rewriting the program from scratch with a different server IP (I lost the source code). On Linux I'd do something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 5555 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2:6666
```

However, the program is working on windows.

I tried using `netsh interface portproxy` command, but it seems as if it's only capable of redirecting **incoming** traffic coming to a certain port. Tackling router settings is not an option in my case. Modifying "etc/hosts" file makes no difference because lines looking like `ip1 ip2` do not work. `netsh routing IP nat` can be only applied to Windows Server 2008.

My goal is to find a solution that can be set up only with the help of built-in utilities.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There's in no built-in way in Windows to route outgoing traffic by
IP address and port, so you need a third-party product.

The
[Multi Port Forwarder](https://www.verigio.com/products/multi-port-forwarder/)
is said to be able to do that.
Unfortunately, the ability for "Filtering/editing IP address"
is not found in the free version and requires the Pro version
($16.95).

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Do you know by chance how did the developers of that program implement it?

Comment: Surely by the one and only method : Hooking system calls system-wide.